# How to iterate map's key and values using for..of in Node?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using Node v5.4.1 and I can't interate over a map's key and values using the for..of loop outlined on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Iterating_Maps_with_for..of).

Using the following code:

```
var map = new Map();
map.set(1, 'hello');
map.set(2, 'world');

for (var [key, value] of map.entries()) {
    console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
```

Results in the syntax error:

```
for (var [key, value] of map.entries()) {
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

Comment: In typescript you need to set `"downlevelIteration": true` in `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Node still doesn't support destructuring. Barring the use of a transpiler, you can do it manually though:

```
for (var entry of map.entries()) {
    var key = entry[0],
        value = entry[1];
    console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the `--es_staging` flag to enable array destructuring in your version of node.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `harmoney_destructuring` flag to enable destructuring support:

`node --harmony_destructuring`.